# Using append to bring a rigged character from one .blend file into another

Tags: mesh, blend-files, append

What is the best way to bring your rigged character into another .blend file using append? Do you have to select both the object and mesh or rig? I tried selecting the object only (the name of my file) but the mesh does not seem to move right or scale. I can only work with the rig. The hands and feet on the mesh, when I select it, stick in place (IK) and the body stretches at the hands and feet. It's not a big problem for me. I can use it that why, just moving the rig. The mesh does what the rig is doing. I was just asking if there is a better way. Thanks.

Comment: Group the rig and mesh objects, then **link** them into the new file, then extract the rig with Ctrl Alt P > "MyRig".